# how to implement random task with python celery async task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I want to perform the same task at different time in a period. for example. In 5 minutes.my code is like this

```
task_period = 5 * 60
task_countdowns = []
last_task_countdown = 0
task_interval = 10
while True:
    last_task_countdown += random.randint(1, 2 * task_interval)
    if last_task_countdown <= task_period:
        task_countdowns.append(last_task_countdown)
    else:
        break
for cd in task_countdowns:
    mytask.apply_async((*args), countdown=cd)
```

my question is:

1. Is there a count limit for append multi celery task in queue?
2. Is there a better way to implement my question?

ps:

1. this is a crontab script and execute every 5 munite

Answer (score 0):

solution:

1 crontab linux sys level

2 celery builtin crontab lib
[celery official](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)